# Is it possible to utilize negative space with HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create/knockout/cutout negative space in the background-color or have images inside of text?

---

[image: Example]

---

Picture Example

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: if you USE SVG you can do these things. SVG can be filled with an image. But I guess that doesnt really help.

Comment: That does help to an extent; I didn't think about that!

Comment: yes you can , I've seen it as CSS. Give me a mo and I'll find it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932946/transparent-text-with-white-background-with-css

Comment: bah humbug....Got there before me.....

Comment: @RaduAndrei neat. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/4zg30ggz/1/

```
.container {
    background: url("http://www.naircare.co.uk/images/main/hub/bg-face.jpg");
    height: 450px;
    width: 600px;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px; 
    height: 100px;
    top: 160px;
    left: 265px;
}
.clear {
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    float: left;
}
.text {
    width: 180px;
    height: 90px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
}
```

If Your trying to do what i think your doing... Let me know if its not right.

Comment: Nothing like what he's trying to do, That's not see through text.

Comment: I appreciate the work around, but I'm more-so trying to find out if there's a way to subtract objects in the front, from the background.