# Transparent text with solid stroke in CSS

Tags: css, border, rgba

I have an image as background on my body (purple kind of gradient).
In the middle of the page there's some text. I want the text to be transparent (i.e. show the purple gradient) but I want a solid color 1px stroke on the text to be visible.

```
text-shadow: 1px 0 red, -1px 0 red, 0 1px red, 0 -1px red;
```

wont work because if you make the text transparent, you'll see the shadows.

```
color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

doesn't make the text see through and..

```
opacity: 0;
```

stuff makes the stroke opaque as well.

Any ideas? Is this possible with CSS only ?

EDIT: I just read about text-stroke. But can't find anything useful.

Comment: wrap it in a div and add border for the div with `display:inline-block`

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932946/transparent-text-with-white-background-with-css

Comment: > i don't fully understand the display:inline-block for this. Thats more to do with how the browser renders the element. (as a block, or an inline element). How would that help me get a border around my text (not the div)?

Basicly what i want is text-color: transparant; & text-border: 1px solid white; (i know those arent correct tags)

> Now trying the related post with background-clip <

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
article h1 {
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
```

}

Comment: would you care explaining what this code does please

Comment: Since font in webs are vectors i guess you could edit them like vectors. Meaning that as in say Adobe Illustrator, add a stroke. This adds a stroke/line around the outside