# How to create transparent text color with css?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a transparent text to be able to see background of that text, Imaging that there is an `h1` on body and body have a background, I want to see the background that is under `h1` with a `background:white` and `color:transparent`

**something like this:**

[image]

But when I set **color** to **transparent**, it will show the `h1` `background color`

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6qne2sa/1/)

there are another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932946/transparent-text-with-white-background-with-css),  But this is not working in Firefox, and I need to have something that works in all major browsers!

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932946/transparent-text-with-white-background-with-css

Comment: Its not transparent text color as the text lies on white background color...

Comment: @K.B.M so what it is?

Comment: Have a look on this post - https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/ . You'll probably need to resort to SVG's fill