# 100% transparant text inside div with solid background

Tags: html, css, text

How can you display a text 100% transparant inside a div with a solid background so that the background is visible inside the text?

So I have a background image on the body, a div with a solid background color and I want the text to be 100% trasparant so the background-image of the body is visible through the text.

I hope you know what I mean :D

Comment: If the text was 100% transparent you'd just see the background colour, are you asking how to cut the text out of the background, so you'd see through the gaps where the letters should be?

Comment: i think you used a wrong wording but the function you should look at is either opactity or background:rbga()

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done with `background-clip:text` --- a css3 property. Also you need to add the background image for text. This will solve your issue, but may support for all the browsers.

```
h1 {
  font-family:'...';
  font-size:25px;  
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background:url(url/image.jpg);
  background-position:bottom;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

Reference: https://scotch.io/tutorials/text-backgrounds-and-gradients-with-background-clip

Also, I have found a similar post in stackoverflow: [Transparent text cut out of background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932946/transparent-text-with-white-background-with-css)

This is great: http://jsfiddle.net/JGPuZ/1/