# Text same 'colour' as background image?

Tags: css, text, fonts, colors, background

I wanted to know how to make text in my nav div the same 'colour' as the big background image behind the nav. I want it to show the part of the background image that it would be otherwise covering.

'color: transparent' and 'color: none' obviously don't work.

```
html {
    background-image: url('backgroundd.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#nav {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #BC1A8E;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: this question has been answered before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13933418/3504059)

Comment: based on your description, there is nothing "obvious" about why color:transparent doesn't work. If the text shows the same as the background, then you can't see the text, because it's *the same as the background*, so what do you *really* want?