# Use text for clip flat background

Tags: jquery, css

Is is possible to do that in code, for dynamic content purpose?
My only fallback is to use an image, but it will not be dynamic.

As you can see, the word "LARIVIÈRE" clip white background to reveal image.

[image]

I found `background-clip` property but it work with image set in background of text area, it's not really what I need in this case.

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparent text cut out of background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932946/transparent-text-cut-out-of-background)

Answer (score 1):

Here is **SVG** approach

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700italic);

body {
  background: url('http://www.onpointpreparedness.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/45202-black-wood.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

text {
   font-size: 70px;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  font-size: 85px;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 30px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  line-height: 0.9;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>LOREM</span>
  <svg width="400px" height="70px">
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
      <text x='10' y="65" textLength='350'>LAVIRIERE</text>
    </mask>
    <rect fill="white" x="5" y="5" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#mask)"/>    
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it would be best to overlay the word as a transparent image and position it over your background image.