# CSS: Transparent Text without Specifying Background

Tags: html, css, user-interface, transparency, gradient

I have a navigation bar with a gradient background, a `<nav>` with a list of links.

When a user is on a certain page, I style the link and list item corresponding to that page differently.  What I can't figure out, however, is how to make the text transparent in such a way that it looks exactly like a cutout into the `<nav>` gradient—so that the background of the parent `<li>` is clear over the text).

I know from answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932946/transparent-text-cut-out-of-background) that the protocol is to specify

```
background: url("image");
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
```

and position the image accordingly so it appears to line up with the background.

How can I adjust the link's gradient so it appears to be in line with the `<nav>`'s? Alternatively, is it possible to make the text transparent *without* specifying a background?

```css
nav { 
  background:linear-gradient(to left, black, red, white);
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: center;
  maring: 0; 
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
}

li.selected { 
  background-color: white; 
}

li.selected a {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, black, red, white);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text; 
}

ul { 
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>A</a></li>
    <li class="selected">
      <a>
        B
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a>C</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: If your background color is solid, you can just use that as your text color.

Comment: I meant behind the navigation, unless I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @TemporaryName, ah—the navigation is what I'm trying to make the text look like it's a part of. Some of the styles on the `<li>`  include a `background-color` which visually separate the text from the navigation.

Comment: Now you see why S.O recommends a [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), thus people can understand what you're trying to say rather than make it like a guesswork

Comment: @Mi-Creativity: Point taken.

Comment: Yeah...this won't work...the gradients are the same **but different widths**....that's the problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D, thanks for the pointer. How can I specify the width and calculate the position of a gradient? Alternatively, how can I make the text transparent without specifying a background layer?

Comment: Pretty much...you can't....unfortunately.