# I need to write with transparent text on a gradient background colour

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can somebody help me to understand how is created the text in this website?
[image]

Basically, what I need is the text colour to be the same as the gradient colour(the background colour of the predecessor div) on a white background.

Thank you!!

Comment: Does the background need to be gradient or is it all one color? The example you have looks like the background is just black

Comment: So in your image whatever is black is actually a continuous gradient?! (I would use an actual image of what I need and I would show what I already tried to code) Please read [ask]

Comment: the example is black but my background is gradient. Anyway, I just need to know what method is used. Black or gradient, doesn't matter. Then I will do research on my own. I've tried already for 1 hour and I cannot find anything.

Comment: and I still don't understand you :D :D

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes. The background image is a gradient.

Comment: I'm not asking you about the background image actually - but to explain a bit better what you need and to show your best try...

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/pvU7r/

Comment: @LGSon :D :D I don't think so :D

Comment: Or this? https://scotch.io/tutorials/text-backgrounds-and-gradients-with-background-clip

Comment: @LGSon nope neither this.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Just trying to understand by using samples :)

Comment: I found it. Thank you anyway to everybody! http://jsfiddle.net/NT7z7/11/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Both my sample links use `-webkit-background-clip: text;` and so does the link OP posted...or you missed that?

Comment: I thought you needed someting like this instead: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D7yy.jpg - which is much closer :D

Comment: EXACTLY LIKE THIS : : i.stack.imgur.com/8D7yy.jpg -

Comment: you are the man

Comment: no you are the man

Comment: You can also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932946/transparent-text-cut-out-of-background

Answer (score 0):

This isn't my best work because it relies on hardcoded positions and background-sizes, but it does work as a quick and dirty solution.

The text *appears* to be clipped from the surrounding black rectangles.

In fact each `span` of text has *its own background*, positioned such that it aligns perfectly with the gradient background of the `h1` beneath.

```css
h1 {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-image: linear-gradient(
red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet
);
}

h1 span {
display: block;
position: relative;
top: 10px;
width: 180px;
height: 50px;
margin: 20px 10px;
line-height: 50px;
font-size: 40px;
text-align: center;
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

h1 span::after {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
background-image: linear-gradient(
red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet
);
background-size: 200px 200px;
background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

h1 span:nth-of-type(1)::after {
content: 'Example';
background-position: -20px -20px;
}

h1 span:nth-of-type(2)::after {
content: 'Text';
background-position: -20px -80px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
<span>Example</span>
<span>Text</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: You can work around having to position the background by positioning the text absolutely, as [is done](https://jsfiddle.net/NT7z7/11/) in the solution [linked by OP](//stackoverflow.com/questions/43574648/i-need-to-write-with-transparent-text-on-a-gradient-background-colour#comment74199897_43574648).