# transparent text but opaque background in css

Tags: html, css

```css
.parent-div {
  background-image: url(path\to\image);
  background-size: cover;
}

.text-div {
  /* make text transparent but not this background */
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="text-div">Welcome!</div>
</div>
```

I want to make the text of **text-div** to be transparent so that I can see background of **parent-div**. and remaining part of **text-div** must be opaque.

Basically I want this effect :

[image: SS]

Comment: I want my text to be transparent not the background

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932946/transparent-text-cut-out-of-background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for my question here:
https://codepen.io/zFunx/pen/EbOQow

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
  background: url(https://web.opendrive.com/api/v1/download/file.json/NTlfMTM2NDExNjNf?inline=1);
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
}
.overlay h1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <h1>Mix-Blending in CSS</h1>
</div>
```