# CSS - Button with transparent text

Tags: css

In my website, I need to display a button where the background is white, and the text gets the color of the background below, which can be a solid color or a background image.

Since the background and the button location are dynamic, I can't use the solutions that where written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932946/transparent-text-cut-out-of-background).

See Example below.

I'm looking for a `css` only solution.

Thanks for helping.

[image: Blue background][image: purple background]

Comment: How is it dynamic? What method is used to choose the color? Why can't you just set the color twice, once on background and once on text, whenever the color is picked?

Comment: @amflare Responsive - in different screen sizes location can be different, which means that text color can be different if the background is an image. Besides, if the button is below a text which is dynamic - the length of the text can affect the location of the button.

Comment: in the question you linked there is a perfect solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29747686/8620333 .. why it's not suitable for you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get this effect by adding the button's background in front of the text, using a pseudo element, and then using [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) on the button (`screen`), and the pseudo element (`color-burn`) to create the cutout effect.

**Note:** this will only work if the button's background is white.

**Note:** `mix-blend-mode` is not supported by IE.

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

.button::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  content: '';
  mix-blend-mode: color-burn;
}

.bg {
  padding: 2em;
}

.bg1 {
  background: purple;
}

.bg2 {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, gold 50%, silver 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg bg1">
  <button class="button">Text</button>
</div>

<div class="bg bg2">
  <button class="button">Text</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As ansered by [Ori Drori](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52320027/4316314), `mix-blend-mode` is the way to go but there's no need to use pseudo elements. Just mix `background-color`, `color` and `mix-blend-mode` depending on the background you want.

Light backgrounds generally needs `color: black` and `mix-blend-mode: lighten` while dark backgrounds needs the opposite to work. A few examples:

```css
.white {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}

.blue {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  color: black;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
  border: none;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  font-size: 6rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  background-color: pink;
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
svg {
  width: 35rem;
  height: 35rem;
}
svg img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <svg>
    <image href="https://yari-demos.prod.mdn.mozit.cloud/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image/mdn_logo_only_color.png" />
  </svg>
</div>
<button class="button white">
  White button
</button>
<button class="button black">
  Black button
</button>
<button class="button blue">
  Blue button
</button>
<button class="button yellow">
  Light yellow
</button>
```