# How to create inset text shadow?

Tags: css

How can I create inset shadow on text? Here is what I am trying to achieve [image]

I am creating this in Figma, on text I have added both drop shadow and text shadow. It seems that Figma only shows source code for drop shadow. Can I achieve inner shadow as well? Values in Figma are these:

- x:0
- y:4
- blur:4
- spread:0
- color: #000
- percentage:25%

```css
h1 {
font-size: 6rem;
margin-bottom: 1rem;
text-shadow: -1px -1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.2), -1px -1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.6);
color: #C92929;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CSS you can experiment with transparency of text color and its shadow.
For example:

```css
h1 {
  color: rgba(201, 41, 41, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 4px #fff, 0 0 0 #000, 0px 4px 4px #fff;
  font-size: 6rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
```

I think, the main problem is calculate that values of colors, to receive advisable effect.

Comment: Is it not possible to make it full red?

Comment: For that solution unfortunately no, because it requires transparency to show the shadow.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but I don't understand why it works. How is the outer shadow being suppressed?

Answer (score 2):

We make a blurred white `text-shadow`, and a black `text-shadow`, while making the color of the text transparent. This can give the illusion that the `text-shadow` is inset... There is no such property, though.

```css
h1 {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 4px #fff, 0 0 0 #000, 0px 4px 4px #fff;
  font-size: 6rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
```

Comment: it needs to be red

Answer (score 0):

You can try with transparency as subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932946/transparent-text-cut-out-of-background) and the code below:

I know result is not the one you expect, because I did not change your shadow. But this the way I use transparantrency that is important.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0px 0px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}
span{
  background: #C92929;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></h1>
```