# Text clip through padding

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my "Register" text as well as my create button background transparent through the padding in order to reveal the background through them.

[here is the render of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG7FR.png)

Right now I am using a linear gradient but the background is a video so eventually, it looks off and I want to see if there's a solution to this.

Here are my HTML and CSS Files

HTML

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}
Sign Up
{% endblock %}

{% block styles %}
{{super()}}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/signin.css">
{% endblock %}

{% block signup %}
  <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="signup">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">REGISTER</h2>
    <input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="ImE1Y2Y2ZGJiMzg0Y2E4MTY0MmZiOTVkZjdhYzMxZTc5MWYzN2QzNTgi.X9lmaA.J_q7OS88E1Dy-J__RgmbVU4XnKA">
    <div class="form-group required"><label class="control-label form-labels" for="username">Username</label>
        <input class="form-input" id="username" name="username" required type="text" placeholder="Enter username" value=""> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group  required"><label class="control-label form-labels" for="email">Email</label>
        <input class="form-input" id="email" name="email" required type="text" placeholder="Enter email" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required"><label class="control-label form-labels" for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-input" id="password" name="password" required type="password" placeholder="Enter password" value="">
    </div>
    <p class="AHAC">Already have an account?<a class="AHAC" href="login"> Login.</a></p>
    <center><button class="form-button" type="submit">Create</button></center>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

CSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap);

.form-signin {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top:8%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

}
.form-signin .form-signin-heading,
.form-signin .checkbox {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top:auto;

}
.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.form-signin .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}
.form-signin input[type="email"] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.form-signin input[type="password"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.form-input {
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 10px;

}
.form-button {
  background: linear-gradient(103deg, rgba(235,131,147,1) 0%, rgba(187,147,227,1) 39%, rgba(235,195,227,1) 100%);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 220px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.form-button:hover {
  

}
.form-signin-heading {
  font-size:40px;
  background: linear-gradient(103deg, rgba(235,131,147,1) 0%, rgba(187,147,227,1) 39%, rgba(235,195,227,1) 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

}
.form-labels {
  font-weight: 600;
  color:grey;
}
.AHAC {
  color:grey;
  font-weight: 600;

}

.AHAC a {
  color:rgba(187,147,227,1);
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*text-transform: uppercase;*/

}
```

Comment: You may find this helpful:  https://codeconvey.com/html5-video-overlay-text/

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65060090/8620333