# Trasparent text in an html a-href button with a threejs animation in background

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

as the title i'd like to have an a-href button with a trasparent text which allow to see behind the transparent text the animation in backgroun made with three js, is possible?

i tyied with

```
mix-blend-mode: screen;
```

in the css class for the a-ref, but don't seems to work since i don't have a backgroun image for the body from css like:

```
body {
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/1600?image=974) ;
}
```

but a threejs animation.
The button is the one below in the picture and the text I need to be trasparent is 'WATCH WORK', the blue meshes in background are waving as a sin/cos function and are my animation in background. I'd like the 'WATCH WORK' text to be TRANSPARENT to see the ANIMATION behind it.

[image]

Thanks you if u can help!

Comment: This should help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932946/transparent-text-cut-out-of-background

Comment: thanks but this still use backgroun image in css: body {
    background: url(http://www.color-hex.com/palettes/26323.png) repeat;
    margin:10px;
}
span { 
    background: url(http://www.color-hex.com/palettes/26323.png) -20px -20px repeat;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    display:block;
}

Comment: Look at the second answer using the SVG

Comment: well i tried but when I try to apply it to my code don't work, the a href tag don't work inside the svg tag