# Applying an image to text

Tags: image, text, overlay

Is there a way to apply an image to the text itself?  Not as a background image, but as an overlay on the text.  For instance, I have an h1 that I would like to apply an image to rather than a font color.

Comment: This question could use some clarification.  Do you mean you want to use text as a *mask* for an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question:
More or less how to use a picture instead of font color:
[“negative” text in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662548/negative-text-in-css)

A nice solution is to use "-webkit-background-clip", but up to know its only supported in Chrome/Safari browsers:
http://www.cssreset.com/fun-with-webkit-background-clip-and-font-face/